# Why does react Apollo on update subscription returns the already updated value as prev?

Tags: reactjs, publish-subscribe, react-apollo

I'm using apollo for a react project and with subscription on the creation, update and deletion of object. I use the `subscribeToMore` functionality to start the subscriptions. The `prev` value of the `updateQuery` callback is the correct value for the creation and deletion subscription. But for the update subscription the `prev` value already contains the updated value. Overall this is really nice, as I don't need to add my custom implementation on how to update the object and can just `return prev`, but I don't understand why this happens. From my understanding the previous value should be returned. Is this just backed in functionality of apollo or is this some weird bug?

Here is the component which implements the subscriptions:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

import * as Entities from './entities';
import * as Queries from './queries';

interface IAppointmentData {
  appointments: Entities.IAppointment[];
  error: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
}

function getAppointmentsFromData(data) {
  return (data && data.appointments) || [];
}

export function useAllAppointments(): IAppointmentData {
  const initialResult = useQuery(Queries.GET_APPOINTMENTS);
  const { data, error, loading, subscribeToMore } = initialResult;

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeNewAppointments = subscribeToMore({
      document: Queries.NEW_APPOINTMENTS_SUB,
      variables: {},
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        if (!subscriptionData.data) {
          return prev;
        }
        const { newAppointment } = subscriptionData.data;
        return Object.assign({}, prev, {
          appointments: [...prev.appointments, newAppointment],
        });
      },
    });
    const unsubscribeUpdateAppointment = subscribeToMore({
      document: Queries.UPDATE_APPOINTMENTS_SUB,
      variables: {},
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        return prev
      },
    });
    const unsubscribeDeleteAppointments = subscribeToMore({
      document: Queries.DELETE_APPOINTMENTS_SUB,
      variables: {},
      updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
        if (!subscriptionData.data) {
          return prev;
        }
        const { deleteAppointment: {
          id: deletedAppointmentId
        } } = subscriptionData.data;

        return Object.assign({}, prev, {
          appointments: prev.appointments.filter(item => item.id !== deletedAppointmentId),
        });
      },
    });

    return function unsubscribe() {
      unsubscribeNewAppointments()
      unsubscribeDeleteAppointments()
      unsubscribeUpdateAppointment()
    }
  }, [subscribeToMore]);

  return {
    appointments: getAppointmentsFromData(data),
    error: !!error,
    loading,
  };
}
```

And these are my graphql queries / subscriptions:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const GET_APPOINTMENTS = gql`
  {
    appointments {
      id
      responsibleCustomer {
        id
        user {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
        }
      }
      companions {
        id
        user {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
        }
      }
      time {
        plannedStart
        plannedEnd
      }
      type
    }
  }
`;

export const NEW_APPOINTMENTS_SUB = gql`
  subscription newAppointment {
    newAppointment {
      id
      responsibleCustomer {
        id
        user {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
        }
      }
      companions {
        id
        user {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
        }
      }
      time {
        plannedStart
        plannedEnd
      }
      type
    }
  }
`;

export const UPDATE_APPOINTMENTS_SUB = gql`
  subscription updateAppointment {
    updateAppointment {
      id
      responsibleCustomer {
        id
        user {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
        }
      }
      companions {
        id
        user {
          id
          firstName
          lastName
        }
      }
      time {
        plannedStart
        plannedEnd
      }
      type
    }
  }
`;

export const DELETE_APPOINTMENTS_SUB = gql`
  subscription deleteAppointment {
    deleteAppointment {
      id
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official Apollo [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/)

> Note that the updateQuery callback must return an object of the same
>   shape as the initial query data, otherwise the new data won't be
>   merged.

After playing around for a bit it seems that if the **id** you are returning is the same as in your cache and the object has the same shape, the update happens automatically.

But if you actually follow the CommentsPage example in the link I [provided](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/) you will see that the id that is returned is **new**, that is why they explicity  assign the object with the new data.

```
if (!subscriptionData.data) return prev;
const newFeedItem = subscriptionData.data.commentAdded;

return Object.assign({}, prev, {
  entry: {
    comments: [newFeedItem, ...prev.entry.comments]
  }
});
```

Ive tested this with my own message app Im working on, when receiving new messages with new **id** I have to return the merged data myself. But when im updating the chatRooms to display which chatRoom should be at the top of my screen (which one has the newest message), then my update happens automatically and I just return prev.

If however you want a work around to explicitly check the data before updating it you could try this [workaround](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3480#issuecomment-472771125) I found on GitHub. You will just need to use a reverse lookup **id** or just a different variable other than **id**.

This is what I would do in your example to achieve this:

```
updateAppointment {
  // was id
  idUpdateAppointment // im sure updateAppointmentId should also work... i think 
  responsibleCustomer {
    id
    user {
      id
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
}
```